# Django - Create a JSON like that

Tags: django, json, django-models

I'm using Django 1.5.1 - Postgresql 9.1

I have database table like this,

```
1.column(id) : [1] [2]
2.column(name)  [josh] [ashley]
3.column(childrens) [david , 8 ; joe , 5] [suzie , 13 ; jennifer , 6]
```

Database table example picture --> http://s9.postimg.org/4kttacbxr/db_example.png

i want to create a JSON file like this:

```
    [{
        id:1,
        name:'josh',
        children : [{
            name:'david',
            age:8
        }, {
            name:'joe',
            age:5
        }]
    },{
        id:2,
        name:'ashley',
        children:[{
            name:'suzie',
            age:13
        }, {
            name:'jennifer',
            age:6
        }]
    }]
```

How i can do this?

Comment: Just iterate over the resultset and make a Python `list` of `dicts`, then use `json.dumps`

Comment: For "it's like that" JSON, I think you want [JSON-nevins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Nevins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solutions is as @Paulo suggested. Iterate over the result set putting the required items into a dictionary then using the json.dump to json-ify the result.

something like this:

```
d = dict()
i = 0
for result in resultset:
    i = i+1
    r = dict()
    r['name'] = result.name
    r['age'] = result.age
    r['height'] = result.height
    d[str(i)] = r
_json = json.dumps(d)
```

Comment: i'm new to django. i will try it. 
(And thanks both of you for quick answers)